# QListWidget returns NULL on default

Tags: qt4, qt5

On everytime when I open a widget I add all the widgetItems and set default to items at zero. First time on application launch widgetItem is returning valid address but closing the widget and again opening returns widgetitem addres as zero.

```
void csGuiSSHModuleSavedConnWindow::showSavedConnWindow(QMap<QString, StoreInfo> &savedConnInfo,const QPoint &pos)
{
    m_savedConnMap.clear();
    m_savedConnMap = savedConnInfo;

    if(m_savedConnMap.keys().count() == 0)
    return;

    m_pConnList->clear();

    foreach (QString connName, m_savedConnMap.keys()) {
       QListWidgetItem* lwi = new QListWidgetItem(connName);
       m_pConnList->addItem(lwi);
       lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    }
    if(m_pConnList->count() == 0)
    {
    return;
    }

    m_pConnList->item(0)->setSelected(true);
    executeDialog(pos);
}

void csGuiSSHModuleSavedConnWindow::slotAddConnection()
{
    QListWidgetItem *listItem = m_pConnList->currentItem();
    QList<QListWidgetItem *> itemsSelected = m_pConnList->selectedItems();
    int count = itemsSelected.count();
    int cc = m_pConnList->count();
    if(listItem)
    { 
      //Returns NULL on second time opening the widget
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing to know about the various view widgets in Qt is that the selected item and the current item aren't the same things, not necessarily.

If you set a current item, it will become the selected item, but not when you do it the other way around. There can be several selected items, but there's only one current item.

Now I do not know why you get a NULL for the second time. I'd need the complete code for this, but I can tell you that this:

```
m_pConnList->item(0)->setSelected(true);
```

should be rather:

```
m_pConnList->setCurrentItem( m_pConnList->item(0) );
```

or:

```
m_pConnList->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

As an example, here's a screenshot of a little widget, the selected item is highlighted, the current item has a focus border:

[image: Listwidget with a selected and a current item]

I hope this helps. If not, please post more of the code or a github link, etc.